CVAT OpenID Connect login doesn't show on Login page
I am trying to set up CVAT to support login using a custom IdP with OpenID Connect. I tried to make changes to base.py and docker-compose.override.yml to configure the server, but once I build and launch CVAT, nothing happens.
I followed this guide, which was directly linked in the code.
Here are the base.py changes:
INSTALLED_APPS += ['cvat.socialaccount.providers.openid_connect',]

...

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "openid_connect": {
        # Optional PKCE defaults to False, but may be required by your provider
        # Can be set globally, or per app (settings).
        'OAUTH_PKCE_ENABLED': True,
        'EMAIL_AUTHENTICATION' : True,
        "APPS": [
            {
                "provider_id": "NAME",
                "name": "Service Name",
                "client_id": "client_id",
                "secret": "secret",
                "settings": {
                    "server_url": "https://server/cvat/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                    # Optional token endpoint authentication method.
                    # May be one of "client_secret_basic", "client_secret_post"
                    # If omitted, a method from the the server's
                    # token auth methods list is used
                    "token_auth_method": "client_secret_basic",
                    "oauth_pkce_enabled": True,
                },
            },
        ]
    }
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_OPENIDCONNECT_KEY = 'client_id'
SOCIAL_AUTH_OPENIDCONNECT_SECRET = 'secret'
SOCIAL_AUTH_OPENIDCONNECT_API_URL = 'https://server/cvat/.well-known/openid-configuration'


SOCIALACCOUNT_ONLY = True

And this is the added docker-compose.override.yml file:
services:
  cvat_server:
    environment:
        USE_ALLAUTH_SOCIAL_ACCOUNTS : true

Since none of this worked, I tried creating a auth_config.yml as follows:
---
social_account:
  enabled: true
  openid_connect:
    client_id: client_id
    client_secret: secret
    domain: https://server.it/

and told CVAT to use it by adding AUTH_CONFIG_PATH = '../../auth_config.yml' in the base.py. This also didn't do anything.
I also tried to ask ChatGPT, and he told me to do things on the front end side of things, but he pointed to non-existing files; therefore, I ignored his suggestions.
Any help and/or suggestions?
